# FPDI: Achieving Accurate Positioning of Text and Image Elements Using Pixel Coordinates

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm currently working on a project that involves embedding text and image elements onto a PDF using FPDI. However, I'm encountering difficulties in positioning these elements accurately.

I've been referencing pixel coordinates from a demo PDF and attempting to translate these coordinates into FPDI's unit measurements for precise element placement. Despite converting pixel values to points (using a ratio of 72/96), the resulting elements do not align perfectly with the original coordinates obtained from the demo PDF.

The specific issue lies in understanding the unit measurement utilized by FPDI and ensuring that the translated pixel coordinates accurately reflect the positions of the embedded elements.

---

***What unit of measurement does FPDI utilize, and how can I accurately translate pixel coordinates to this unit for precise element placement? I aim to ensure that pixel coordinates align perfectly with FPDI-embedded elements, replicating the original positions from the demo PDF. Any insights or approaches would be greatly appreciated.***

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using for text and image embedding:

```
public function addTextElement($pdf, $element): void {
    // Conversion of pixel coordinates to points
    $x = $element['response_meta_json']['cord']['x'] * (72 / 96);
    $y = $element['response_meta_json']['cord']['y'] * (72 / 96);

    // Set font and position
    $pdf->SetFont($element['response_meta_json']['font-family'] ?? 'Arial', '', $element['response_meta_json']['font-size'] ?? 12);
    $pdf->SetXY($x, $y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(
      $element['response_meta_json']['area']['width'],
      $element['response_meta_json']['area']['height'],
      $element['response_meta_json']['value']
    );
}

public function addImageElement($pdf, $element): void {
    // Conversion of pixel coordinates to points
    $x = $element['response_meta_json']['cord']['x'] * (72 / 96);
    $y = $element['response_meta_json']['cord']['y'] * (72 / 96);

    // Manual positioning for testing purposes
    $x = 132.29166667;
    $y = 200.81875;

    $imageSrc = $element['response_meta_json']['img_src'];

    // Image embedding with coordinates
    $pdf->Image(
      $imageSrc,
      $x,
      $y,
      $element['response_meta_json']['area']['width'],
      $element['response_meta_json']['area']['height']
    );
}
```

Comment: There are no pixels in a PDF. By default, FPDF works in mm (as mentioned in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Olivier . My concern is related to my attempt to clone a demo PDF using the FPDI library. The demo PDF's coordinates are in pixels (px) for both the X and Y axes. Despite converting these coordinates to millimeters (mm) for use with FPDI, I still face alignment issues. The goal is to precisely replicate the element positions from the demo PDF within FPDI. Any advice on achieving this precise alignment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free tool for watching coordinates in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971243/free-tool-for-watching-coordinates-in-pdf)

Comment: The tool given in the link (PDFBox PDFDebugger) will give coordinates expressed in points (1/72 of inch). Either convert them to mm or configure FPDF to use points instead of mm.

Comment: In figma  i have a demo pdf , on that pdf i place a text element and get its coordinate in base of pdf , so then i pass x and y coordinate to the backend to process same exact pdf , and compare this 2 pdf so that it looks like same after embedding text elements to the pdf . 

But if i directly set x and y coordinate it is not matched to the original pdf element positioning , i also tried to convert x and y axis to mm , pt but nothing work to look like exact pdf element positioning .